# Using SQL Cursor, To find the date > 45 days difference from initial date, then again from 2nd date found, again > 45 and find next date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @quoteReference NVARCHAR(20)
Declare @policyNo NVARCHAR(20)
Declare @todaysDate DATE
Declare @time int
Declare @ddiff int
Declare @cnt varchar(10)

Declare EmpCursor Cursor for
select quote_reference, Miscellaneous_TodaysDate, diff from #temp1

OPEN EmpCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM EmpCursor INTO @quoteReference ,@todaysDate,@ddiff WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    
    select @quoteReference = quote_reference
           --@policyno = policy_policyNo,
          -- @time = Miscellaneous_CurrentTime
           from #temp1 where
           Miscellaneous_TodaysDate = @todaysDate and diff > 45
    
    if
           @ddiff < 45
            update #temp1
            set counts = 'N'
            where Miscellaneous_TodaysDate = @todaysDate
    else
            update #temp1
            set counts = 'Y'
            where Miscellaneous_TodaysDate = @todaysDate
   FETCH NEXT FROM EmpCursor INTO @quoteReference, @policyNo, @todaysDate
END
CLOSE EmpCursor
DEALLOCATE EmpCursor
```

The first time `quote_reference` entered in the database is 31/05/2021.
I need another date where the same record came again in the database after more than 45 days (so in this case its 64 days i.e 03/08/2021) then 03/08/2021 date becomes my 2nd initial date and from that date same rules and conditions, i.e. to find date where the same record
entered again after more than 45 days difference.

DATA:

[image]

Comment: How married are you to using a cursor? I very much doubt it's anywhere close to the best way to solve this. Instead I'd join the table to itself. And rather than building up a temp table for this I'd look to use a CTE, so this can all be in one single execution plan without loss of indexing or statistic data.

Comment: I have tried every possible ways of doing this, but CURSOR is the only way I found it could be possible. All other functions will give me only 1 date (with diff > 45 days) not the other date.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the LAG function. link here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

I dont remember when was the last time I used cursor, you can very much achieve what you want in a SQL statement

Comment: I have tried using LAG and LEAD but they are processing rows consecutive, I want days difference from initial date and then again from next date.

Comment: That's why you join the table to itself. The join conditions and include the minimum date diff. Hmm... and using an APPLY instead of a JOIN you can also limit the "joined" set to one row.

Comment: will you be able to provide the create statements and expected output. I think we should be able to use LAG.